# Jquery Children

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to create a nice gallery for an e-commerce. - all the current code is [here](https://gist.github.com/mmoscosa/c7ddb9e94e4a481d93b6)

The front-end layout I got from [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/27/3d-grid-effect/) followed the tutorial and it worked like a charm.

Then to add the payment module I decided to  add a floating div:

```
<?php foreach ($tes as $te): ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $te['Product']['id'] ?>">
            <div class="shop-actions">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <span href="#" class="list-group-item active comprar-menu-button">
                        <?php echo __('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Carrito de Compras'); ?>
                    </span>
                    <span href="#" class="list-group-item comprar-menu">
                        <h3>Agregar al carrito</h3>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('default' => false, 'inputDefaults' => array(
                                            'div' => 'form-group',
                                            'label' => false,
                                            'wrapInput' => false,
                                            'class' => 'form-control'))); ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <?php 
                                    echo $this->Form->input('cantidad', array(
                                                                            'options' => array(
                                                                                                50 => "50gr",
                                                                                                100 => "100gr",
                                                                                                150 => "150gr",
                                                                                                200 => "200gr",
                                                                                                250 => "250gr",
                                                                                                500 => "500gr",
                                                                                                1000 => "1kg",
                                                                                                'mayoreo' => "mayoreo",
                                                                                               ),
                                                                            'empty' => '(Seleccionar)',
                                                                        ));
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 mayoreo">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <?php echo $this->Form->input('mayoreo', array('label' => '', 'type'=>'number')); ?>
                                  <span class="input-group-addon">KG</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 subtotal">
                                <div id="<?php echo $te['Product']['price']; ?>"><span>$0.00 MXN</span> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                </br>
                                <?php   echo $this->Form->submit('Agregar', array('div' => 'form-group','class' => 'btn btn-info col-md-12')); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
                        <hr />
                        <h4>Ademas en tu carrito</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lung Jing <span class="pull-right">200gr</span></li>
                            <li>Pu Erh <span class="pull-right">1kg</span></li>
                            <li>Lapsang Su shang <span class="pull-right">10kg</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class="pull-right">Subtotal: $2,500.00 MXN</span>
                    </span>
                </div>        
            </div>
            […]
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <span class="loading"></span>
    <span class="icon close-content"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
```

Then I tried to add some **jQuery** to make the UX nice and smooth…

```
    function formatCurrency(total) {
    var neg = false;
    if(total < 0) {
        neg = true;
        total = Math.abs(total);
    }
    return (neg ? "-$" : '$') + parseFloat(total, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString();
}
$('.comprar-menu-button').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':visible')){
            $(this).css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });

});
$('.cantidad-te').change(function(){
    var value, product, precio, cantidadEspecial;
    value = $(this).val();
    product = $(this).parent().parent();
    precio = $(this).parent().parent().next().next().children();
    cantidadEspecial =product.next();
    if (value === 'mayoreo') {
        cantidadEspecial.show();
        precio.children().html('especifique cantidad');
    }else{
        cantidadEspecial.hide();
        subtotal = precio.attr('id') * value;
        precio.children().html(formatCurrency(subtotal) + ' MXN');
    }
});
```

In theory it works, however it only works for the last element on my teas product.

### Expected outcome

When clicking on any element it should:

- show the div with the shopping cart
- slideToggle should show the form to add product to shopping cart
- When selecting an element from dropdown it should:

  - update with correct price

### Current outcome

- Only slideToggle() works for last element on my grid.
- when changing values on dropdown list it does not make the changes specified.

### Additional info

- To see a live version of how the 3D grid works visit [here](http://qihouse.mx/galeria) (this is not the version am currently working with as I havent pushed the changes)
- The code for live version is [here](https://github.com/mmoscosa/qihouse)
- Page Source (HTML Outcome) - [here](https://gist.github.com/mmoscosa/4fe4b310ad8ce4308a74) as pointed out by [@AlexAtNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347185/jquery-children#comment37642608_24347185)

Thank you

Comment: As you question is HTML/JavaScript related, could you please replace the HTML/PHP code with its result, e.g. HTML output?

Comment: @AlexAtNet Thanks, I decided to put the page source (HTML output) inside a gist better: [here it is:](https://gist.github.com/mmoscosa/4fe4b310ad8ce4308a74) https://gist.github.com/mmoscosa/4fe4b310ad8ce4308a74